# webcam error in kaltura CE while trying to record

Tags: drupal-6, red5

I have an application in Drupal and we need to record video through webcam or upload a video file, we have installed kaltura module in Drupal.

1.) We have kaltura CE 1.5 and Red5 installed. When we try to record through webcam in Kaltura's console, we are getting error like

`Error: ArgumentError: Error #1063 text: Error #2095`
`Error: ReferenceError: Error #1069 text: Error #2095`

Still it records the video through webcam, but after saving it, if we try to play it's not playing.

It creates a node in drupal, but in Drupal also it's not playing.

In folder, I found flv files, i can run them in VLC.

2.) When we record in Drupal, it throws error:

> Could not initiate connection to the server.

What's missing?